# Unable to boot freshly installed Ubuntu-mate

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I've done dozens of dual-boot systems in the past (Windows + Linux), however the bellow issue is the strangest one I have ever seen. Have a look:

1. I've performed a fresh Windows 10 Installation on a clean SSD (Intel SSD Pro 1500 240GB m.2).
   At this stage My SSD hold one System Restore partition (500 MB) and one 128GB partition for Windows. Both partitions are primary. So far so good, all works.
2. Next I plugged in an Ubuntu-Mate 16.10 live USB and started the installation. During this process I chose to create a third primary partition (ext4 for "/") and a fourth primary partition for swap.
   During the install process I chose to install Grub on the MBR of the SSD (which shows up as /dev/sda)
   The Ubuntu-Mate installation went really smooth. I could see in the log that the Grub installation identifies the Windows OS and includes it in the menu.

However after reboot, grub throws error that filesystem is unknown and leaves me in a grub rescue shell.

Running the "ls" command gives me a list of partitions, however none of their filesystems is recognized when I run again "ls (hd0,#)" against each of them....

I have found many articles on how to rescue Grub by booting with a live CD/USB and tried most of them, however no luck.

The only thing that works is to boot with Windows 10 DVD and repair, but that's not dual-booting any longer...

Other things I have tried with no luck:
- checked that the ext4 partition got created and that I can access its contents from the live-USB
- checked that the SSD has the latest firmware
- checked that I can partition the rest of the SSD with windows-only partitions

Does anyone have some more in-depth knowledge of what could go wrong (or what I might be doing wrong)?

There are many other things one could try, such as trying other distro or trying on a HDD in the same laptop, but this trial-and-error approach is time-consuming and I am hoping to save some time.

Comment: Have you disabled the secure-boot flag in your uefi-bios? From what I know, this is enabled by default on windows 10 machines and prevents any other OS than Windows 10 from booting. It's a vague guess, though.